# Is it possible to connect to derby through odbc

Tags: odbc, derby, jdbc-odbc

Is it possible to connect to the derby database through odbc on a windows 10 machine?  I have the jdbc-odbc bridge from Java 7.  Found this:

```
Derby network server
The Derby network server provides traditional client/server access to the Derby 
engine. The network server lets clients connect over TCP/IP using a subset of 
the DRDA protocol. The network server supports connections from networked JDBC, 
ODBC/CLI, Perl, and PHP clients.
```

But can’t find any examples or instructions on how to connect with ODBC/CLI

Comment: What is that quoted text from? Can you provide a reference? A link? A source?

Comment: Oh, in a different question that you asked I see that you are looking at IBM documentation for Derby 10.0 and 10.1. Indeed, those releases, when Derby was more closely connected to IBM, **did** support ODBC, but that functionality has disappeared from more modern versions of Derby.

Comment: @Bryan here's the link https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_charter.html  So, I'm still confused.  What does "...The network server supports connections from networked JDBC, 
ODBC/CLI, Perl, and PHP clients."  mean? Can we connect to Derby through ODBC or not?  If not, why the heck is this in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's quite out of date, I'm afraid. I wrote a bug report to get it corrected: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-7000